# How to efficiently sort a recursively defined Stack?

Tags: data-structures, sorting, recursion, stack

I am trying to implement a recursively defined Stack and sort it in Java.
I don't have a particular usage of this program in mind. I found this approach of stack implementation a bit useful while implementing persistent stack.
I know Stacks are not made for sorting but one can consider using two stacks to implement a job scheduling queue which needs to be sorted for which stacks used for queue implementation must be sorted based on some resource parameters.

Is there any efficient method apart from copying the elements from Stack in array, sorting them and again pushing them on stack? (I know C/C++, Java)

```
//Stack definition:
Stack
{
    E element;
    Stack topOfSubStack;
}
```

Comment: Hello, it appears you are new to our site - please [check out the purpose of this site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour). It appears you are asking a homework question, which is off-topic, so I have downvoted your question.

Comment: Its not a homework question I was just trying to implement a recursively defined Stack?
question is purely out of curiosity.

Comment: My apologies - it looks rather like a copy/paste from a homework assignment. I believe asking your question in more detail would be a good idea. In the meantime, perhaps [this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525117/whats-the-fastest-algorithm-for-sorting-a-linked-list) - you can probably effectively think of your "recursive stack" as a singly-linked list.

Comment: question [as it was posted originally](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/256073/1) wouldn't win you friends at this site

Comment: I'm a newbie. I'll improve :)

Comment: What's the overall goal? Do you have a particular usage in mind? Typically, stacks aren't sortable, because you only care about what's on top of the stack. If you care about data order and performance, a balanced tree with stack operations (push/pop and shift/unshift) might be a more appropriate option.

Comment: I don't have a particular usage of it in mind. I found this approach of stack implementation a bit useful while implementing persistent stack.

Comment: Sounds like Towers of Hanoi http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi

Comment: well, smart analogy there @Peter.
But I want to do it efficiently. Tower Of Hanoi will be very much slow considering that Stack contains large no. of elements.

Comment: @geek Then, the only way I see to empty the stack to an efficiently sortable data structure, sort and then to push the sorted data back on the stack. Stacks are not made for sorting.

Comment: Yeah that too  I'm considering to do it using HashMap so that it would be more faster or should I use Array and use Collections.Sort() in java?
I know Stacks are not made for sorting but what if I'm using Stacks to implement a queue which needs to be sorted as in consider the queue used by OS for job scheduling.

Comment: @geek Why would you use a stack to implement a queue? Stacks by definition can't be queues, as they only operate from one end, and queues must operate from both.

Comment: Practically while implementing a queue u might use an array or a linked list. While doing insertions and deletions in an array it takes O(n) time.Same is case while using linked list if it has only one pointer head to point the whole list.
If u implement Queue using 2 stacks you can either implement in such a way that time complexity of insertion operation becomes O(1) and time complexity of deletion operation becomes Amortized O(n), which is better than using array or linked list to implement the queue.

Comment: [Here's a reference link for implementation of queue using two stacks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-using-stacks/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a derived mergesort

you can grab chunks of the stack and sort them separately (standard divide and conquer)

then you can simply merge as follows:

```
struct node{
int element;
node* next;
}

node* merge(node* begin1, node* end1, node* begin2, node* end2){

    node* head;
    node* tail;
    if(begin1==end1)return begin2;
    if(begin2==end2)return begin1;

    if(begin1->element < begin2->element){
       head = tail = begin1;
       begin1=begin1->next;
    }else{
       head = tail = begin1;
       begin2=begin2->next;
    }
    while(begin1!=end1 && begin2!=end2){

        if(begin1->element < begin2->element){
           tail->next = begin1;
           tail=tail.next;
           begin1=begin1->next;
        }else{
           tail->next = begin2;
           tail=tail.next;
           begin2=begin2->next;
        }

    }
    if(begin1==end1)tail->next=begin2;
    if(begin2==end2)tail->next=begin1;
    return head;
}
```

You can split the array by starting at an increment of 1 and then grabbing chunks that large merging them 2 by 2, concatenating them and doubling the chunkLength each time.

Comment: Can you provide the time and space complexity of your code?

Comment: @geek O(n log n) time and O(1) space (as good as you can get with a comparison sort)